# Create sql container from Docker.DotNet api with -p, -d flags

Tags: c#, sql-server, docker, docker-api

I am trying to create a sql server docker container using the docker api via [Docker.DotNet](https://github.com/Microsoft/Docker.DotNet)

The powershell to do this according to [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-linux-2017) is as follows

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=<YourStrong!Passw0rd>" `
-p 1433:1433 --name sql1 `
-d microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest
```

I have the following code which creates a container

```
public async Task StartAsync()
{            
    await client.Containers.StartWithConfigContainerExecAsync(Id, new ContainerExecStartParameters
    {
        Env = new List<string> { "ACCEPT_EULA=Y", $"SA_PASSWORD={SaPassword}" },
    });
}
```

but I cannot figure out how to pass the `-p`, `--name`, and `-d` parameters, and can not figure out from the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.37/#operation/ContainerCreate) how this is supposed to be done